# How to install a python-module 'Parfile'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, installation, module

Good day,

I have a python code and this code has the following line at the beginning.

`from parfile_parser import Parfile`

I am using ipython (python version 3.7) and the OS is Ubuntu 20.04. The above line gives me an error as below.

" No module named 'parfile_parser' "

So, I tried to find this module by googling to install on my desktop, but I could not find it. Do you happen to know how I can install this module and how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `parfile_parser` is not on PyPi. Where did you get this code from? They should tell you more about this module and where to find it.

Comment: This looks like this might be relevant: https://github.com/limodou/par

Comment: Hi Matthias, it is a data-analyzing tool (Adaptive-binning package) in https://fermi.gsfc.nasa.gov/ssc/data/analysis/user/. Let me contact them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried to install it on a desktop, did you install it in your virtual environment. If not try to install it in your virtual environment and then check.

Comment: I mean, I tried to find the module by googling. But, I could not find it. Thanks.